# How to show specific div based on database value?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and MySQL. I want to have a simple website, where users can log in to a simple dashboard. (No one can sign up on this website, it is meant only for my clients and I gave them the login details. Yes, I know that the password should be stored hashed, but I don't need it in this scenario.)

In the dashboard, I want to show the specific div based on database value. For example, if the row `workout_1` in the table `users` is `true`, I want to show the div `workout_1` etc. If the value is `false`, the div should be hide.

Based on some tutorials, I figured out how to set up a simple login/logout process. Now I am stuck on how to set up this show / hide div procedure. What I know is that I have to get the query somehow, but as I said, I am new to PHP and MySQL and a little advice from you I would really appreciate.

This is authentication.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$DATABASE_HOST = '**';
$DATABASE_USER = '**';
$DATABASE_PASS = '**';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'tablename';

$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {

    exit('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {

    exit('Please fill both the username and password fields!');
}

if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = ?')) {

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();

        if ($_POST['password'] === $password) {

            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            header('Location: ../dashboard.php');
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect password!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username!';
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

This is dashboard.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

And this is HTML I want to show / hide based on MySQL query.

```
<div id="workout_1">There are some notes for users they attended the 1st workout.</div>
<div id="workout_2">There are some notes for users they attended the 2nd workout.</div>
<div id="workout_3">There are some notes for users they attended the 3rd workout.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are very basics of the MySQL and my first advice would be to review other similar questions on SO and read about connecting MYSQL to PHP.

You need to change a bit your query and take also `workout_1` value from table users.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password, workout_1 password FROM users WHERE username = ?')
```

And bind value of this parameter to the variable.

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $password, $workout_1);
```

When you have suitable variable you can just make conditional statement in proper place in your code.

```
<?
if((bool)$workout_1) {
    echo'<div id="workout_1">There are some notes for users they attended the 1st workout.</div>';
}
?>

<div id="workout_2">There are some notes for users they attended the 2nd workout.</div>
<div id="workout_3">There are some notes for users they attended the 3rd workout.</div>
```

Boolean values (true or false) in database should be stored in the columns with type Integer (1 - for true, 0 - for false). Also you should avoid mixing PHP code with View layer (HTML), but for the beginning it's all right.

EDIT:
Second approach. To include in dashboard.php.

```
$DATABASE_HOST = '**';
$DATABASE_USER = '**';
$DATABASE_PASS = '**';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'tablename';

$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {

    exit('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT workout_1 FROM users WHERE id = ?')) {

    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($workout_1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tajni, thanks for your help. I believe I am almost there :) If I try your code, nothing happens. The div stays hidden no matter if the value is 0 nor 1.

Comment: what `var_dump($workout_1)` outputs in both cases? Do you include your PHP code into view file (with html)?

Comment: NULL in both cases. As you suggested, I edited valuables in `authenticate.php`. But I have to include it somehow in `dashboard.php` as well?

Comment: Yes, to need to retrieve your query again in `dashboard.php`. I included this code to the answer. You should consider creating common file that you can include to both files.

Comment: what do you get when you run `SELECT workout_1 FROM users WHERE id = ?` with proper id in mysql?

Comment: Still NULL. So there is some problem with database, I guess? In the navbar I am using `<?=$_SESSION['name']?>` to show logged users name and that works correctly.

Comment: No. Check query directly in your database. `SELECT workout_1 FROM users WHERE id = 22`, for user ID=22.  Maybe you don't have specified workout_1 for that user.

Comment: It works correctly when I check it in my database, I have specified it for all the (two :-)) users. I even followed your advice in the original comment and the column is INT.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I missed type of ID. It should be integer, not string.

Comment: Still the same, the result is `NULL`. But I don't want to bother you, Tajni, and thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure. Inform us what was wrong with your code when you find out.